# Postgres periodically slows down on heroku RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rails-postgresql

I faced with periodic RoR 3 application unavailability. Usually I have 15 minutes unavailability period each day. The problem doesn't relates with application load and I can't find any errors in logs. The only errors I see is H12 Request timeout. I changed postgres plan to production but the problem occurs anyway. 
On newrelic I see Postgres serious response time increase before H12 errors. 
Please help.

Pavel.

Comment: can't help without code.. new relic shows you excatly what controller and what action is causing this.. Most likely, you code hangs somewhere

Comment: For example query Team.find() which take in average 5 ms takes about 1 second when the problem occures. Also there is a strange detail that DelayedJob.find stops polling during the problem.

Comment: As @NickGinanto said it check what processes take long. Query your data in baches, use caching. Sign up with new relic you will even get a cool t-shirt